# Compose state is not recomposing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have viewModel with data class

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MetricUnitViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    val state = MutableStateFlow(SettingsState())

    fun onItemChecked(settingItem: SettingItemAction.Checkable.CheckableItem) {
        val newList = state.value.settingItems.map { item ->
            item.isChecked = item == settingItem
            item
        }
        state.value = state.value.copy(settingItems = newList)
       
    }

    data class SettingsState(
        val settingItems: List<SettingItemAction.Checkable.CheckableItem> = emptyList()
    )
}
```

and the screen

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MetricUnitScreen(
    viewModel: MetricUnitViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    settingsData: SettingsData,
    onItemChecked: (SettingItemAction.Checkable.CheckableItem) -> Unit,
    onBackClicked: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
    state.settingItems.forEachIndexed { index,  item ->
            MetricUnitItemView(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                item = item,
                isLast = index == state.settingItems.lastIndex
            ) {
                onItemChecked(it)
            }
        }
```

But seems like `onItemChecked()` and invoking `state.value = state.value.copy(settingItems = newList)` gives no effect on @Composable screen. Its completely ignored even though on the ViewModel side I can see modified list